# Paperclip to upload images to S3 in Rails. The files upload at a very slow rate. A work-around?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, delayed-job, swfupload

I'm working on a rails app where the user will be uploading large quantities of images.

My current setup: Using SWFUpload to upload multiple files at once using the Paperclip plugin with S3 storage. After the original image is uploaded to S3, Delayed_Job is used for the post processing (thumbnails, etc).

The problem I have is that the images upload at a very slow rate. I'm assuming the default Paperclip setup is that the image will go from the user to -> my server to -> s3.

I was thinking that I can have the images upload directly to s3 but I'm not sure how to implement that with Paperclip and post processing. I couldn't find any plugins or examples dealing with this.

Does anyone have suggestions? If not, can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Tim

Answer (score 3):

I've ran into this same problem a few times. The way I solved it was by creating 2 models, a `Image` model and a `TempImage` model, which inherits from the `Image` model. This requires you to have a `type` column on your `Image` table. The `TempImage` model saves the image locally, then when you access it from the `Image` model directly and resave it, it will follow whatever is defined in the `Image` model, being Amazon S3.

Example:

```
# Will save in the database as a TempImage inside the Image table
temp = TempImage.create(:asset => File.new('some_path', 'r'))

# When you find it again through the Image model, it bypasses the type column
# so next time you save it, it is saved as an Image.
amazon = Image.find(temp.id)
amazon.save!
```

Here is my delayed job:

```
class MoveToS3Job < Struct.new(:temp_revision_id)
  def perform
    upload = Image.find(temp_revision_id)
    temp_path = File.expand_path("tmp/uploads/#{upload.asset_file_name}", Rails.root)
    upload.asset = File.new(temp_path, 'r')
    upload.save!

    if File.exists?(temp_path) && !File.directory?(temp_path)
      File.delete(temp_path)
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    # If the record wasn't found, do some sort of
    # error report, but don't keep it in the queue.
  end
end
```

Here is the `TempImage` model:

```
class TempImage < Image
  has_attached_file :asset, {
    :path => ":rails_root/tmp/uploads/:basename_:updated_at.:extension"
  }
end
```

Then the original `Image` model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Validations
  validates :asset, :presence => true

  # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => {
    :preview => ['100x100#', :png],
    :thumb => ['50x50#', :png]
  },
  :default_style => :thumb,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'bucket-name',
  :s3_credentials => File.expand_path('config/s3.yml', Rails.root),
  :path => "photos/:id_partition/:style.:extension"
end
```

Your original `Image` model should always contain your post processing, as that will be done in the background.

You can always overwrite some methods to make it a little cleaner, but this gives you a better idea of how it works and what you need to do to so you can have it work like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up going the route of uploading directly to S3 which offloads the work from your Rails server, please check out my sample projects:

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash and MooTools-based FancyUploader to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-FancyUploader

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash/Silverlight/GoogleGears/BrowserPlus and jQuery-based Plupload to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload

By the way, you can do post-processing with Paperclip using something like this blog post describes:

http://www.railstoolkit.com/posts/fancyupload-amazon-s3-uploader-with-paperclip